# Why do we say that the force on a body is equal to the rate of change of momentum, if they are directly proportional? Isn't there a missing constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, dimensional-analysis, units

I'm just a bit confused.
I understand that $F = \Delta p/\Delta t$, but I also know that $F$ is proportional to $\Delta p$, hence shouldn't $F = k \Delta p/\Delta t$?
Why is it that we ignore the constant when setting the two quantities equal?

Comment: We define our units such that this constant is 1

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the comment about units...

In the SI system of units, the unit of force is the Newton. One Newton is defined as the force required to give a mass of one kg an acceleration of one metre per second per second. So, in effect, there *is* a constant of proportionality $k$ in $F=k \Delta P$, but if we work in SI units then the definition of the Newton makes $k$ equal 1.

Most other systems of units also define their unit of force so that $k$ equals 1. For example, in the CGS system the unit of force is the dyne, which is defined as the force required to give a mass of one gram an acceleration of one centimetre per second per second.

However, if for some reason we measured mass in grams, length in metres, time in seconds and force in Newtons then one Newton gives a mass of one gram an acceleration of $10^3$ metres per second per second, so we would have to make $k$ equal to $10^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small misunderstanding.
$$p = mv$$
$$F = ma$$
$$a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$F = m\frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$= \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$$
Since $F$ is dependant on $t$ and $v$,
$$\Delta F \propto m\Delta v,\Delta t$$
This is not the same as saying $F \propto p$, because the change in time ($\Delta t$) has to be constant. It has to be change in $t$, because  that means if $t$ were constant, the acceleration ($\frac{dv}{dt}$) will be $0$, meaning $F = 0N$. So if we account for the change in $t$, the change in $F$ will be constant and changing momentum $p$ will proportionally change $F$.